# Is '"snapshotting" a correct word?

Tags: gerunds, is-it-a-word, attributive-nouns, zero-derivation, deverbal-nouns

For example, as part of the information message of some computer script:

> **Snapshotting** the file...

Can we write *snapshotting* instead of *taking the snapshot*? Is it still correct?

---

I've found an example usage of that word on Wikipedia, in the following context:

> ... is not a **snapshotting** scheme but a system-level incremental backup service ...

and

> Time Machine is not a file system and it does not make use of a **snapshotting** feature. It is only included here as a reference.

Source: [Snapshot (computer storage)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29)

Comment: What is a "correct" word? What do dictionaries say?

Comment: Most of the online dictionaries redirects _snapshotting_ to the main 'snapshot' word, so it's not clear whether this word is correct. I haven't found much details about this usage of word, it's not very popular. For example [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snapshotting) mentions _snap·shot·ting_ as _to photograph informally and quickly_, but for me this still doesn't prove whether it's a valid English word or not. This could be similar to [_timeouting_ word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/101837/5365), which is not a word, but I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Are you asking whether we can derive the verb  *to snapshot* from the noun *a snapshot*, and then whether that verb has a regular -ing inflection we can use as a gerund and then rederive that back from a verb into a deverbal noun again to be used attributively to modify another noun like *scheme* with?  If so, then that seems so fundamental and thus wholly unremarkable a  process of English grammar that I remain confused about why you are asking whether English works this way. ;)

Comment: The _-ing_ inflection doesn't work for all verb words, for example it didn't work for _timeout_. So, yes, I'm asking whether this verb has a regular _-ing_ inflection, or it creates some kind of slang/buzz word.

Comment: The *-ing* inflection is one of the few perfectly regular features of English verbs.The only verbs to lack them are those which also lack infinitive forms: specifically, the modals. We therefore say that modal verbs are “defective” in English because they lack certain inflections. But *timeout* is not a modal, and it is not defective. Moreover, *timeouts* is also never a verb: it is only ever a noun, just as *logins, screwups,* and *hangouts* are. Break them up to inflect as verbs: *timing out a process, logging in a user, screwing up the grammar, hanging out casually*. See how that works?

Comment: The only free online dictionary that I would cite as at least something of an authority to give the verbal polyseme is Wiktionary; it adds the totally predictable inflections @tchrist mentions. I'd not shrink from using the verb in informal situations or in computerese, but I'd avoid it in formal non-technical English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with everything you've said. Do notice that the 1989 OED2 mentions it, and in what context.

Comment: @kenorb I would argue that *it's a timeouting foul* is perfectly understandable, even if not normal usage—and something that would typically be rephrased. Asking if you ***can*** write something often has an answer in the positive. Asking if you ***should*** something is different, and has an answer that's a matter of opinion, especially when no context has been provided.

Comment: What the OP may be interested in is not only whether this word is occasionally used by some people, and whether it will be readily understood, but also how formal or informal it is. That may to some extent be a matter of opinion, but it is not entirely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, *snapshotting* is a recognized word!

The OED says that ***snapshotting*** derives from the verb *to snapshot*, which in turn derives from the noun *a snapshot*. <sup>[[*paywalled link*]](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183041)</sup>

They provide this citation:

> ### ˈsnapshotting *adj.*
>
> - **1978**   *Nature*   7 Dec. 647/2
>   Mr Sankhala also remarks that the snap-shotting tourist is so preoccupied with shutter speeds, lens apertures and focussing that he fails to see anything around him.

That entry is from the Second Edition of 1989, and has not yet been updated for the Third Edition.

Snapshotting a process or file in the context of computing is probably newer than that citation.

---

## On inflectional morphology applied to verb+particle compounds

I’ve asserted that if *snapshot* is a verb, then it should come as no surprise to learn that it has an *‑ing* inflection by way of *snapshotting*. However, the asker has suggested in comments that not all verbs have *‑ing* inflections. They have offered *timeout* as one example of a verb that lacking *‑ing* form.

The first statement is true only in a special, technical way involving defective verbs. The second statement is based on a misunderstanding.

That’s because the *‑ing* inflection is one of the few perfectly regular features of English verbs. The only verbs to lack nonfinite inflections like present participles (same form as gerunds) and past participles also lack infinitive forms: specifically, the modals.

We therefore say that modal verbs are “defective” in English because they lack certain inflections. So for example the modal verb *should* has no nonfinite forms like  **shoulding* or **shoulded*, nor can it be used as either a bare- or *to*-infinitive. You cannot make someone *should anything.

But *timeout* is not a modal, and it is not defective. It works exactly as *snapshot* does.

But **unlike** *snapshots*, *timeouts* is only ever a noun and never a verb — just as *logins, screwups,* and *hangouts* are.  Just as the plural of the noun *passerby* is the noun *passer**s**by* where we think of those pieces individually when we want to inflect them, you must first break up compounds that were originally made up of a verb plus a particle smashed together when you want to inflect them as verbs.

- NOT: *timeouting a process, BUT RATHER: timing out a process, timing a process out

  NOT: *timeouted a process, BUT RATHER: timed out a process, timed a process out
- NOT: *loginning a user*, BUT RATHER logging in a user, logging a user in

  NOT: a *loginned user, BUT RATHER a logged in user
- NOT: *screwupping the grammar, BUT RATHER: screwing up the grammar, screwing the grammar up

  NOT: *a screwupped grammar, BUT RATHER: a screwed up grammar
- NOT: *hangouting casually, BUT RATHER: hanging out casually, casually hanging out

  NOT: we *hangouted yesterday, BUT RATHER: we hung out yesterday

Just as *tomorrow* was once written *to-morrow*, *nowadays* was once written *now-a-days*, and *passersby* once written *passers-by*, often when first coined these compounds begin life as open ones separated by blanks or as conjoined ones written with hyphens, but these all seem to get worn down with time.

- a few time-outs > a few timeouts
- some snap shots > some snap-shots > some snapshots
- snap-shotting > snapshotting

---

## *Snapshotting* or *Snapshooting*?

On the subject of *snapshotting*,
there is also a long-attested noun ***snap-shooting***, meaning the process of taking snap-shots — or snap shots or snapshots :)

Via the citations given in the OED,<sup>[[*paywalled link*]](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183039)</sup> we can see the historical progression from writing this word as an open compound to writing it as a hyphenated one to writing it with neither hyphens nor spaces:

> - **1872**   *Gentleman's Mag*.   Dec. 664
>   Snap shooting, as it is termed, is very effective sometimes by experienced gunners.
> - **1883**   *Cent. Mag*.   Aug. 493
>   Snap-shooting is generally understood to consist in putting the gun to the shoulder and firing the instant it is in position.
> - **1979**   G. Macdonald *Camera*   iv. 57
>   Snapshooting was..a..haphazard affair... Most snaps were still portraits of family and friends.

Comment: Thorough, but perhaps one should beware [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb)] the over-generalisation.